# Report is not recognizing the parameter being passed

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a report and deployed on Reporting Services Server. This report is populated using a stored procedure which receives an input parameter: @RecordID.

In the report also, I added a variable with the name RecordID.

In my Visual Studio project, I added Report Viewer control and set the path of the server report. When I open this report on Web Page, it displays error:

```
Parameter 'RecordID' does not exist on this report
```

The code in the code-behind file is:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("RecordID","3");
        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
```

**Edited**

I added a variable using Report Properties in Business Development Studio. Below is the image. This variable is set to receive value of the parameter.

[image]

Comment: You said you added Variable on the Report is it a parameter you have added? Does the Report run by it self on the Reporting server. DO you have the option to set the Parameter when you run the Report?

Comment: Check twice your report (what if ShowParameterPrompts is true and no params provided). If you added a **parameter** with name RecordID then it must be there...

Comment: If I am not passing parameter using code-behind, it prompts for parameter value.

Comment: @bhupendrapatel Yes the variable is set to have parameter value.

Comment: What does GetParameters return?  My thought is you initialise the report later than this and the report viewer doesn't know about them yet.

Comment: Please see my Edited post. Added Image.

Comment: You're adding a VARIABLE, not a PARAMETER named RecordID.

Comment: @Adriano But the variable is set to receive the value from the parameter? Anyway, than how to add a parameter to the report?

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: In Business Development Studio's Solution, I added a DataSet in the Shared Data Set folder. The DataSet is connected to a stored procedure. This report is linked to stored procedure.

Comment: Add a parameter to the report then add a link to that parameter in the dataset. You may not need report variables.

Comment: I want to know how to do the first one, i.e., add parameter to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [image] you see the steps to add a new parameter and to link it to the Dataset.